# How to calculate $\lim_{n \to +\infty} (n+x) \sin^2(n+x)$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

How to calculate
$$\lim_{n \to +\infty} (n+x) \sin^2(n+x)$$
for a  fixed $x \in \left[0,1\right]$ ?

I've seen that the question $\lim_{n \to +\infty} n |\sin n|$ is difficult, but I wonder whether this one is much easier to solve.

Any ideas for help? I only thought that because $n$ is integer, for a certain $N$, when $n>N$ we can conclude that $\sin(n+x)$ can be dense in $\left(0,1\right]$.

Added:My question is whether 
$$\lim_{n \to +\infty} (n+x) \sin^2(n+x)= + \infty$$
is right?

Comment: I don't think the limit exists

Comment: Sorry, what I want to figure out is whether it equals ＋∞

Comment: Heuristically I suspect that the limit does not exist -- would expect that for many large $N$, there exists some $n$ with, say, $N \le n \le 10N$, and having the property that $n+x$ a "small" angle, i.e. with $n + x = 2\pi k + \theta$ where $0 \le \theta \le 1 / N$. With an angle that small, $(n+x) \sin^2 (n+x)$ would be on the order of $n(1/N)^2 \le 10/N$. So would expect that the liminf is 0 and the limsup is $\infty$. No idea right now how to prove it though, or how hard it is to prove (or disprove..)

Comment: I think this can be made precise using https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equidistribution_theorem (see also https://mathoverflow.net/questions/75777/elementary-proof-of-the-equidistribution-theorem the top answer by David Speyer and possibly others)

Answer (score 0):

The limit does not exist. To see this, recall the fact that the limit existing implies the sequence is bounded. Thus, boundedness is a necessary condition for convergence. This sequence is not bounded so the sequence does not converge.

Comment: Oh sorry, what I want to figure out is whether it equals ＋∞

Comment: In what sense? It's unbounded from above but if you graph your sequence you'll see that it returns to $0$ infinitely often since $\sin(x)$ has period $2\pi$.

Comment: For every $N$, dose it exist a $n＞N$ such that $(n＋x)\sin^2 (n+x)$ returns to 0 ?

Comment: But n is integer, I think I've said that